# How to control back and forth for react native webview component through custom components in ios?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a scenario in which I have to build a webview component with custom back and forward buttons in React Native view for IOS.

I have created an app with a web-view component. It only shows plain browser, not any control of it for back and forward buttons.

Comment: Can you provide more details with codes sample so community can guide you?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the components you added in the view must in back. 
You can use like below example:

`<Yourcomponents style={{ position: "absolute"}} />`
`<webview style={{ position: "relative"}} />`